# ReactJS setState in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map() function that loops over  json data stored in the state of my class. In each  loop, it displays a component that has an onClick mouse event set. It doesn't work and outputsan error "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded..." What can i do to make it work ?

Here's a sample of the code i use :

The constructor of my class :

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     storeList:  storesLoc.stores,
     currentStoreName: storesLoc.stores[0].name,
     currentStoreCp:  storesLoc.stores[0].cp,
     currentStoreAddress:  storesLoc.stores[0].address
}
```

and the sample of code in the render method

```
<ul className="ul-locations">
{this.state.storeList.map((store, i) => (
 <li>
    <StoreItem  
     key={i} 
     cp={store.cp} 
     name={store.name} 
     selected={store.selected} 
     onClick={this.changeCityInfo(i)}/>
  </li>
  ))}
  <li>
     <Shuffle className="col-2"></Shuffle>
     <a href="#" className="ml-2 mr-2 col-10">Changer de Magasin</a></li>
```

Comment: Full code would help

Comment: You're calling the event handler while rendering - `onClick={this.changeCityInfo(i)}`. Change to arrow function `onClick={() => this.changeCityInfo(i)}, or better yet pass the handler, and `i` to the `StoreItem`, and handle it inside it.

Answer (score 2):

you should pass a function reference to onclick, but you you executing it, and inside that you probably call some setState, hence infinite loop; wrap it with an arrow function that returns the function you want and you are good to go

```
onClick={()=>this.changeCityInfo(i)}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This invokes `changeCityInfo` function with argument `i` on each render.

```
onClick={this.changeCityInfo(i)} // Wrong expression, invokes the function
```

Instead, pass an arrow function with empty parameter list and call inside that function:

```
onClick={() => this.changeCityInfo(i)} // Correct expression, doesn't invoke but point
```

Now it will only get invoked on click.

Comment: it will pass an event object to the `changeCityInfo` function instead of `i`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with the `onClick` prop that you are passing to `StoreItem` - try this instead:

```
<StoreItem 
    {...otherprops}
    onClick={() => this.changeCityInfo(i)}
/>
```

Comment: This could use some clarification, that they're calling the function rather than passing it to the click event.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It will help me to understand

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** You were getting the error because the function `changeCityInfo` was getting called for every iteration of the map function

**Solution:** In react whenever we have to handle events or pass function to another component we have to do it in the following way `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(arg)}>` so in your case follow this:

```js
  <StoreItem  
   key={i} 
   cp={store.cp} 
   name={store.name} 
   selected={store.selected} 
   onClick={() => this.changeCityInfo(i)}
 />
```

> Have a look at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) doc from official react site you will get a better understanding of it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using parameters, you can use something like this on onClick props

```
 <li>
    <StoreItem  
     key={i} 
     cp={store.cp} 
     name={store.name} 
     selected={store.selected} 
     onClick={() => this.changeCityInfo(i)}/> // try this
  </li>
```